# 'search database using multiple checkboxes'

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a page with multiple check boxes on, each box correspond to each ingredient (fig.1)

Database is called 'Recipes'

(fig.1)
Table name = 'ingredients'

- ID   ingredient
- 1    olive oil
- 2    black pepper
- 3    beef stock

and so on......

this table is the main one and as the site grows so will the number of ingredients and check boxes to match.

I also have several more tables, each being a recipe (fig.2)

(fig.2)
Table name = 'Lasagne'

ingredient_id

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6

and so on......

for each recipe the ingredient_id matches one of the ID's in the the main table (fig.1).

---

I want to have it so that someone can select as many check boxes as they want. When they click on submit, it brings back each recipe starting with the closest matched to the ingredients followed by a-z  at the top.........I know when you type echo that it prints what you say on the screen...If I had a table in place on the search.php page, could each recipe result be echo'd into each row in the table in in order as mentioned above?

This is what I have so far....

index.html..

```
<form action="search.php" method="post" name="search_form" onsubmit="return checked boxes" >
<table width="571" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="183" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="Olive oil" id="1"/> Olive oil<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="black pepper" id="2"/> Black pepper<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="beef stock" id="3"/> Beef stock<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="lean steak mince" id="4"/> Lean steak mince<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="mushrooms" id="5"/> Mushrooms<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="red onion" id="6"/> Red onion<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="garlic" id="7"/> Garlic<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="tomato concentrate" id="8"/> Tomato concentrate<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="lasagna sheets" id="9"/> Lasagna sheets<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="milk" id="10"/> Milk<br/></td>
<td width="171" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="cheese" id="11"/> Cheese<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="butter" id="12"/> Butter<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="plain flour" id="13"/> Plain flour<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="chopped tomatos" id="14"/> Chopped tomato<br/></td>
<td width="195">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>'
```

search.php

```
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 


$dbhandle = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","" ) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("recipes",$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select recipes");'
```

Comment: try something, show us what you tried, you will get good help. Now you are asking us to code it for you.

Comment: I don't know if i completely understand you but i guess you want to store some recipes that can have multiple ingredients wereby you want to allow the user to add different recipes with ingredients that you provided (so these are static?)

Comment: I dont want the user to add recipes, but to simply search for them based on the ingredients selects.

Comment: You have a db table for each reciepe? I don't think it's a very good idea.
You should have one table named `reciepes` with the next fields (just for instance):`id` , `name` , `ingridients`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you will never add or remove recipes from your system, your overall design is flawed.  The schema most people would use for this is more like:

1. A table of ingredients: ingredient_id, name, ...
2. A table of recipes: recipe_id, name, ...
3. A table of recipe ingredients: recipe_id, ingredient_id, quantity, ...

With your design, you need to create a new table for each recipe.  Furthermore, to find recipes that use an ingredient, you need to search dozens of tables each in a separate query (or one very messy query with lots of UNIONs).

With this design, you just search RECIPE_INGREDIENTS and join to RECIPES so you can get the recipe names to print out.

Either way, you want to build the WHERE clause in the query by checking each ingredient option in turn and appending it to the clause.  In pseudocode:

```
$whereClause="WHERE ingredient in ("
for each ingredient {
   if(user selected $ingredient) {
      $whereClause .= "'" . $ingredient . "',"
   }
}
$whereClause .= ")"
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use the LIKE command in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE agent LIKE something
```

Comment: Can you have a look at this as I've tried my best to understand what I need to be doing but I got this error...

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 47

Comment: $where=''; 
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) 
    { 
        $where=' where '; 
       if(IsChecked($_POST['search'],'olive oil')) 
       { 
            $where=" Product_description IS LIKE '%olive oil%' OR "; 
       } 
       if(IsChecked($_POST['search'],'black pepper')) 
       { 
            $where=" Product_description IS LIKE '%black pepper%' OR  "; 
       }  
//and so on 
       $where = rtrim($where,'OR'); 
    } 

    $result = mysql_query("Select * from ingredients $where"); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))  
    { 
      echo $row['Id'].' '.$row['ingredient']; 
    }

Comment: You can take a look at this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: He doesn't have a table "recipes"